# SQL joins and nested query returning different records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently working on a project which is supposed to take some arbitrary input data, do some natural language processing, and dynamically generate a corresponding SQL query. I also have a "reference" set of SQL queries which I can use to compare my SQL against to verify that the SQL generation is accurate.

This is one such SQL query that I've generated:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t0.airline_code 
FROM ( 
    SELECT airline.* 
    FROM airline, flight 
    WHERE ( 
        ( airline.airline_code = flight.airline_code ) 
        AND 
        ( flight.flight_days = 'DAILY' ) 
    ) 
) 
AS t0 
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT airline.* 
    FROM airline, flight, airport_service, city 
    WHERE ( 
        ( airline.airline_code = flight.airline_code ) 
        AND 
        ( flight.from_airport = airport_service.airport_code ) 
        AND 
        ( airport_service.city_code = city.city_code ) 
        AND 
        ( city.city_name = 'BOSTON' ) 
    ) 
) 
AS t1 
ON t0.airline_code = t1.airline_code 
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT airline.* 
    FROM airline, flight, airport_service, city 
    WHERE ( 
        ( airline.airline_code = flight.airline_code ) 
        AND 
        ( flight.to_airport = airport_service.airport_code ) 
        AND 
        ( airport_service.city_code = city.city_code ) 
        AND 
        ( city.city_name = 'DALLAS' ) 
    ) 
) 
AS t2 
ON t1.airline_code = t2.airline_code;
```

Running this returns the following columns:

```
airline_code
------------
AA 
CO 
HP 
TW 
DL 
NW 
UA 
US
```

The reference SQL, however, returns slightly different results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT airline.airline_code
FROM airline
WHERE airline.airline_code IN
        (SELECT flight.airline_code
         FROM flight
         WHERE (flight.flight_days = 'DAILY'
                AND (flight.from_airport IN
                         (SELECT airport_service.airport_code
                          FROM airport_service
                          WHERE airport_service.city_code IN
                                  (SELECT city.city_code
                                   FROM city
                                   WHERE city.city_name = 'BOSTON'))
                     AND flight.to_airport IN
                         (SELECT airport_service.airport_code
                          FROM airport_service
                          WHERE airport_service.city_code IN
                                  (SELECT city.city_code
                                   FROM city
                                   WHERE city.city_name = 'DALLAS')))));
```

Result:

```
airline_code
------------
AA 
DL 
TW 
UA 
US
```

Obviously, the two are different in that the first one is using joins while the second one uses nested SQL statements. However, this doesn't appear to be causing any problems for the other generated SQL/reference SQL that I'm working with, which are structured similarly (the generated SQL uses joins, the reference SQL is nested).

I'm fairly new to SQL, and know next to nothing about databases, so I could be missing something stupidly obvious, but for the life of me, I can't see why the two SQL statements are returning different results. They seem functionally identical, as best as I can tell. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong, and how I can fix the generated SQL to match the reference?

If it matters, I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Comment: I think first query will return all daily flights from boston and to dallas, and second one will return all daily flights from boston to dallas. You should add AND t0.airline_code=t2.airline_code to first query

Comment: @bksi that's not exactly true, t0.airline_code is already equal t2.airline_code because of transitivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**bksi** is right, the problem is in the first query.

Look: you get all companies having daily flights in first query.

Then you `RIGHT JOIN` companies having flights from Boston - it means you now selected companies having daily flights (from anywhere) AND (anytime) flights from Boston, but not exactly daily flights from Boston.

And yes, the third join gives you companies that at the same time have daily flights, have flights from Boston and have flights to Dallas.

Second query, with nested statements, gives your only companies with daily flights from Boston to Dallas.